# How to determine what marked section a line is found within a file in BASH?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file that has marked sections with a ** preceding the title like this, containing various questions:

```
**Animals

What kind of food do pigs eat?
Where to koalas live?

**Food
Who made the world's largest pizza?
Where is cheese made?
What kind of bread is popular in France?
```

Given the question as a variable, such as "Where is cheese made?" how can I return the name of the section that question is found under, e.g. "Food" would be the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v var="Where is cheese made?" 'index($0,var) && !/^\*\*/{print val;next} /^\*\*/{sub(/^\*\*/,"");val=$0}'  Input_file
```

We could mention variable `-v var="...."` which you want to look and print its respective `**` line's value.

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution.

```
awk -v var="Where is cheese made?" '
index($0,var) && !/^\*\*/{
  print val
  next
}
/^\*\*/{
  sub(/^\*\*/,"")
  val=$0
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk -v var="Where is cheese made?" '     ##Starting awk program here and mentioning variable named var whose value if whereis cheese made?
index($0,var) && !/^\*\*/{               ##Using index out of the box function of awk programming to get a match of variable var in current line and making sure line is NOT starting from *
  print val                              ##Printing variable val here.
  next                                   ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^\*\*/{                                 ##checking condition if a line starts from * then do following.
  sub(/^\*\*/,"")                        ##Substituting starting ** with NULL here.
  val=$0                                 ##Creating variable val whose value if current line.
}'  file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `awk`

```
var="Where is cheese made?"
awk -v var="$var" -F"**" '/^\*\*/ {a=$NF} $0==var {print a}' file
Food
```

- input variable `-v var="$var"`
- Set field separator to double star `-F"**"`
- `/^\*\*/ {a=$NF}` if line starts with `**`, save last field in variable `a`
- `$0==var {print a}` if line equals to input, print variable `a`